# Who can I get Pearson correlation very fast from Queue<double>

Tags: c#, performance

I have 2 queues as follows:

```
Queue<double> RtnQueue = new Queue<double>();
Queue<double> RtnQueueTmin1 = new Queue<double>();
```

each queue has approx 30K elements.

The queues are constantly changing and I need to calculate Pearson correlation on each change:

```
Value = MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Correlation.Pearson(RtnQueue, RtnQueueTmin1);
```

Here is method:

```
public void Update(double datum, DateTime utcDT)
{
    if (RtnQueue != null && RtnQueue.Count >= Length)
    {
        RtnQueueTmin1.Dequeue();
        RtnQueueTmin1.Enqueue(RtnQueue.Last());

        RtnQueue.Dequeue();
        RtnQueue.Enqueue(datum);

        Value = MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Correlation.Pearson(RtnQueue, RtnQueueTmin1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (RtnQueue.Count == 0)
            RtnQueueTmin1.Enqueue(0);
        else
            RtnQueueTmin1.Enqueue(RtnQueue.Last());

        RtnQueue.Enqueue(datum);
        Value = 0;
    }
}
```

This is slow for thousands of changes. How can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Queue<T>` is not an indexable collection `RtnQueue.Last()` will be very slow because it iterates the whole collection.

Possible solutions:

- Use a `List<T>` instead, where accessing the last element is very fast. Unfortunately, here `Dequeue` (`RemoveAt(0)`) will be very slow. You might need to maintain a dynamic start/end position to overcome this issue.
- Use a `LinkedList<T>`. Use `AddLast` instead of `Enqueue` and `RemoveFirst` instead of `Dequeue`. Access the last element by the `Last` property instead of the extension method. Unfortunately, `LinkedList` is quite slow in general (especially enumerating the list) as it uses a chain of reference type nodes instead of an underlying array.
- Alternatively, you can try my [`CircularList<T>`](http://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Collections_CircularList_1.htm), which is functionally compatible with `List<T>` but adding/removing elements at the first/last position are equally fast. You can download it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries).

Comment: Wow, Enormous speed difference. I will credit you with answer when able to

Answer (score 1):

You can keep aggregated values for correlation calculation (sum(x), sum(x^2), sum(y), sum(y^2), sum(x*y)) from previous steps and just update these values each step:

```
var lastX = RtnQueueTmin1.Dequeue();
var lastY = RtnQueue.Dequeue();

var newX = RtnQueue.Last();
var newY = datum;

sumX = sumX - lastX + newX;
sumX2 = sumX2 - Math.Pow(lastX, 2) + Math.Pow(newX, 2);
sumY = sumY - lastY + newY;
sumY2 = sumY2 - Math.Pow(lastY, 2) + Math.Pow(newY, 2);
sumXY = sumXY - (lastX * lastY) + (newX * newY);
```

But you will need to calculate Value yourself, without using library (formula is taken from Wikipedia):

```
Value = (Length * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / 
 (Math.Sqrt(Length * sumX2 - Math.Pow(sumX, 2)) * Math.Sqrt(Length * sumY2 - Math.Pow(sumY, 2)));
```

Comment: I would ideally like to credit you and @Gyorgy Koszeg for an answer, but I will credit him as his circularlists made the essential difference to my performance